# Do you have a pen? Can such sentences be converted into passive form?

Tags: passive-voice, possessives

> Do you **have** a pen?

The verb in the question is "have" which is a possessive verb. Can such questions be asked in passive form?

Comment: *Is a pen had*? (That's quite unusual, but it doesn't seem actually wrong.)

Comment: Active voice: "He cut the rope"; Passive voice: "The rope was cut."  Passive voice including agent: "The rope was cut by him."             Active voice: "You have a pen."; Passive voice: "A pen is had.";  Passive voice with subject: "A pen is had by you."    Made into a question: "Is a pen had by you?".......     They'll send you to the loony bin for asking this.      How about "Is a pen available?", no this isn't in the passive voice.  Can I ask why you would like to know if this can be asked in the passive voice?

Comment: Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: I heard someone justifying the passive voice of the question in concern as "Is the pen owned by you? "

Comment: But native speakers never use such stative verbs in passive forms. At times they tolerate in past as.. The Villa was owned by Thomas

Answer (score 1):

According to [Grammaring.com](https://www.grammaring.com/verbs-which-cannot-be-used-in-the-passive-voice), *have* cannot be passivized.

> Certain state verbs are not used in the passive even if they are transitive. Examples of such verbs are: belong, have (own), lack, resemble, suit etc.